# It is possible to test widget with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm writing tests for my app, and one part is involving a widget. I can't find anything on the subject: it is possible to automatically test widgets with Espresso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Espresso is made to run tests in the process of an activity. Widgets belong to the home screen (app).

UI automator could be a solution for testing widgets (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

Comment: Thanks! Digging into the doc